# Content of XML view does not get loaded on adding a container

Tags: html, xml, sapui5, sap-fiori

Content of my view does not get loaded on adding `l:VerticalLayout`. If I remove it, the view works fine then. I'm adding `xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"` too. In the console, it shows the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: resource ns/HTML5Module/view/View1.view.xml could not be loaded from ./view/View1.view.xml. Check for 'file not found' or parse errors. Reason: Error: **Invalid XML:** <mvc:View controllerName="ns.HTML5Module.controller.View1" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" >"

Please see the code below:

[image: Screenshot of my UI5 view code]

I am using SAP Business Application Studio.

Comment: Please include code in the question itself, not in images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#:%7E:text=Attributes%20must%20be%20separated%20from%20each%20other%20by%20one%20or%20more%20ASCII%20whitespace.):

> Attributes **must** be separated from each other by one or more ASCII whitespace.

I.e. in your case, it should be:

```xml
<!-- Correct XML syntax: one or more whitespace between the attributes: -->
<Title level="H2" text="Layout Example"></Title>
```

Instead of:

```xml
<!-- Invalid syntax: no whitespace between `level` and `text`: -->
<Title level="H2"text="Layout Example"></Title>
```